# diferrence between new vue & vue.createapp

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm studing Vue.js and I have learned that every Vue application starts by creating a new Vue instance with the Vue custructor `new Vue({ }))`.

So far everything is clear, untill t I came across `Vue.createApp({ })` which I don't understand if it does the **same job** as  `new Vue({ }))` ? and if they can they be **used interchangeably** ? is **one more recommended than the other** ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is different syntax for different vue versions from version `vue 2.7 naruto` you can only use `createApp` and for older versions you can only use `new Vue`

Comment: createApp is Vue 3

Comment: is there any benefits to use `createApp({ })` over `new Vue({ })` ? at the performance level maybe ?

Comment: @EstusFlask createApp is `vue 2.7 naruto` or high

Comment: @atifthb `createApp` allow tree shaking

Comment: @TachibanaShin It would be a breaking change if new Vue() weren't working in 2.x. It's composition api that was added in 2.7, not createApp. This is the only mention of it in v2 docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-2-7#Behavior-Differences-from-Vue-3